# Select a specific img element out of a div

Tags: jquery, select, html

I have a div element with multiple img elements in it. I want to select one specific img out of it, that is tagged with the classname "active" and then get the html value of this specific image. The rest of the images has epmty classes.

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="src1" class>
  <img src="src2" class="active">
  <img src="src3" class>
</div>
```

When I select the outer class with `$(".images").html()` I get a string that contains all 3 inner images. But When I try to do it like this `$(".images.active").html()` I only get returned an undefined. Why is it working the first time but not the second? And how can I select only the element tagged with active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$(".images .active").attr('src');
```

You need a space between the classes to select descendant elements, otherwise you're telling it to look for an element with both classes. Also, image elements have to .html() value; you probably want the src attribute.

Comment: I wanted to get the whole line as a string, so when I select my element I get back <img src="src2" class="active"> but your method works just fine too, I can work with the src.
But out of curiosity, is there a command that would return me the whole line?

Comment: Ah, well you can also try `$('.images .active')[0].outerHTML`

Answer (score 2):

the selector should be

```
$(".images .active")
```

here is [a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KZWb/)